# Showing $||F'(x)y||\geq c_3||y||$ in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, banach-spaces, newton-raphson

I'm looking at Lemma 2.1 in Reddien's paper "On Newton's Method for Singular Problems". [image]

I'm still fairly new to Banach spaces. So I'd appreciate a hint as to why Lemma 2.1 is an "easy" consequence of Taylor's theorem. I'm confused on both part (i) and (ii), but I'm hoping some help with part (i) will allow me to understand part (ii) on my own.

Edit: Notation: $N_1$ is the null space of $F'(x^*)$, and $X_1$ is closed subspace such that $F'(x^*)X_1=X_1$ and $X=N_1\oplus X_1$. We assume that $F\in C^3$.

My current idea is this: by Taylor's theorem, for $y\in X_1$ we can write $ =F'(x^*)y+F''(x^*)(x-x^*)y+o(||x-x^*||^2)y.$ Then by the triangle inequality $||F'(x)y||≥\bigg(\frac{||F'(x^*)y||}{||y||}−||F''(x^*)||\,||x-x^*||−o(||x-x^*||^2)||\bigg)||y||.$ So now we can pick $x$ close enough to $x^*$ so that the term in front of $||y||$ is positive, and I think we can bound $\frac{||F'(x^*)y||}{||y||}$ away from zero since the range of $F'(x^*)$ is closed, that being $X_1$.

Comment: If you could add the notation used in theorem 1? $N_1$ should be the nullspace of the Jacobian at the singular root, what is $X_1$ again?

Comment: $X_1$ is taken to be a closed subspace such that $X=N_1\oplus X_1$ and $F'(x^*)X_1=X_1$. So it seems like $X_1$ is the range of $F'(x^*)$?. If $y\in X_1$, since $F(x^*)X_1=X_1$ there exists an $x\in X_1$ such that $F'(x^*)x=y$.

Comment: My current idea is this: by Taylor's theorem, for $y\in X_1$ we can write $F'(x)y=F'(x^*)y+F''(x^*)(x-x^*)y+o(||x-x^*||^2)y$. Then by the triangle inequality $||F'(x)y||\geq \bigg(\frac{||F'(x^*)y||}{||y||}-||F''(x^*)||\,||x-x^*||-o(||x-x^*||^2)||\bigg)||y||$. So now we can pick $x$ close enough to $x^*$ so that the term in front of $||y||$ is positive, and I think we can bound $\frac{||F'(x^*)y||}{||y||}$ away from zero since the range of $F'(x^*)$ is closed, that being $X_1$.

Comment: It would be better if you edited substantial information directly into the question. Use comments only for discussions on the question formulation. /// The idea looks correct, but if you only demand continuity of the second order derivative, then the little $o$ has order 1, the remainder would have big $O$ order 2 if the second derivative were Lipschitz or better.

Comment: I have added the corrections to the problem statement above. Is assuming $F\in C^3$ sufficient for the little $o$ term to have order 2? I have not seen this continuity requirement in what I've read about Taylor's theorem in Banach spaces.